# kotlinx.serialization Json config: use singleton or build every time?

Tags: kotlin, jvm, singleton, kotlinx.serialization

I'm building a Kotlin server application. I know that I will need a specific Json configuration such as `Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true }` throughout.

My question is whether it makes more sense to declare a top-level `var` (or maybe an `object` with the config as a property) and use that everywhere, or whether to create a new `Json {}` within each function.

I guess my concern with using a singleton is a tie-up in the case when I have multiple simultaneous requests coming in all of which need to use the config. I don't know enough about JVM internals or the kotlinx architecture to know if that is an issue. Meanwhile, creating a new config within every function seems highly inefficient, creating new objects every time.

```
// which to choose?

// top-level val
val myJson : Json = Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true }

// top-level object with property
object myJConfig {
  val myJson : Json = { ignoreUnknownKeys = true }
}

// create a new config within a function
class myClass {
  fun myFunc() {
    val myJson : Json = { ignoreUnknownKeys = true }
    ... rest of function here ...
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no issues with multiple users of a certain "thing". The issue is with concurrent modification, so as long as none of your procedures actually change something in your object, a singleton will be fine.

Comment: @Alex.T  thanks. no there will not be any modification. I was concerned about a slowdown if one request is currently using the parser, another request would have to wait until the first one is done. If parsing a long JSON string takes, say 250ms, am I limiting my server from handling any more than 4 requests per second?

Answer (score 0):

Instance of `Json` is tread-safe (so are all `KSerializer`s). It's instance of `Encoder` or `Decoder` that is context-specific for object you encode/decode.